# Problem with building graphic using ListPlot

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

I want to build the graphic using `ListPlot` but it doesn't work.
I get list in next form:

```
{{0, {600.}}, {1, {691.94}}, {2, {883.229}}}
```

If I try to build the graphic I get the empty graph, but if i rewrite list in form:

```
{{0, 600.}, {1, 691.94}, {2, 883.229}}
```

I get nice graph:
[image]

How we can see, the problem is in additional brackets. How do i remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListPlot[Flatten /@ {{0, {600.}}, {1, {691.94}}, {2, {883.229}}}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[.025]]
```

[image]